# Page scrolling to top when executing JQuery script

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

can you please help me out? Can't get this working and it's driving me nuts.

I have a GridView inside an UpdatePanel. One of the links in the gridview uses the following JQuery script:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, GetType(), "Script1", "$('#divid1').click(function () {$('#divid2').toggle('slow');});", true);
```

So I am registering the script like this and it works fine. The issue I am having is that everytime I click on  the link, the page scrolls to top. How I can execute the JQuery script onclick without the page scrolling to top?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have `#` in your  `href` attribute the browsers usually do jump to top.
  see if you have this problem and your code has a `#` in href

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. But the solution was to add onclick="return false;", since I still need to link to now go anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('divid1').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // your other code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Because you are using `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock ` this will go server side so scroll is going to top.

Instead of this use Jquery for link click event

$('divid1').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // your other code
});
```